# SVN directories not showing up in localhost when using WAMP

Tags: svn, localhost, wamp

I recently installed WAMP for actual local use. I've worked on live development servers but now am working on localhost. I've managed to get multiple virtual hosts setup on my WAMP/Vista 64-bit box but am having difficulty with directories pulled from SVN.
I have four vhosts setup. Two work well and they are not tied to any SVN just yet. 
I'm also using TortoiseSVN in case it makes any difference.
However, the other projects are coming from SVN repositories. When I view these two projects I get the following error:

*Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.*

The way I setup the vhosts is as follows:

**httpd.conf**

```
# Multiple Virtual Hosts
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.1.0>
    ServerName testone.local
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/root/projectone/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.2.0>
    ServerName testtwo.local
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/root/projecttwo/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.3.0>
    ServerName testthree.local
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/root/projectthree/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.3.1>
    ServerName testfour.local
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/root/projectfour/"
</VirtualHost>
```

And here's the '**hosts**' file:

```
# Localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost


# Project One
127.0.1.0      testone.local

# Project Two
127.0.2.0      testtwo.local


# Project Three
127.0.3.0      testthree.local


# Project Four
127.0.3.1      testfour.local
```

Everything works just fine. So if you want to tell me I'm doing something wrong then by all means point out a few things. But as it stands, it works and I'm content using different IPs and/or named-based vhosts.

The problem comes in not being able to see the directories and files in the projects that are tied to an SVN. Whenever I visit http://testxxxx.local I get the error message at the top of this post. Please provide some suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: Can you add the error message you get in the Apache error log?

Comment: Please look into your Apache error.log file. Every 500 error gets recorded there with a detailed error message pointing out the root of the problem (the message you see on screen is the default message for the user/visitor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error : The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Symptom : svn directory not listed on web server

Checks :

1)checked apache error log from file system
2)error shown in log is
[client 127.0.0.1] C:/wamp/www/Elecite2/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration 
3) checked mod_rewrite.so is present in the wamp directory(C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\modules)

AND in the httpd.conf (C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\conf)

uncomment lines with mod_rewrite entry i.e
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Ranjeeta

Comment: Good answer. Thank you!  I've since moved onto Zend Server CE. Though, the setup is still somewhat similar when dealing directly with the hosts and httpd.conf files.